# React. Redux persist sends two identical requests

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

i am using redux-persist and refux tool kit. I have a dependency, if the slice (RTK) changes, then there is a request to the server. Without a persister, there is 1 request, as it should be. But when the persister is connected, 2 identical requests go at once.

this i effect to send request:

```
  const {
    simpleOutgoingData,
  } = useTypedSelector(({ simpleMortgage }) => simpleMortgage)

  const { postSimpleMortgageCalc } = useActions()

  useEffect(() => {
    postSimpleMortgageCalc(simpleOutgoingData)
  }, [simpleOutgoingData])
```

This is slice

```
const simpleOutgoingData = createSlice({
  name: 'simpleOutgoingData',
  initialState: {
    target: 'payment',
    mortgageAmount: 500000,
    loanType: 'regular',
    interestRate: 1.6,
    amortizationMonths: 300,
    isIncludeAmortizationTable: true,
    rateTermMonths: 60,
    paymentFrequency: 'monthly',
    extraPayment: 0,
    annualPrepayment: 0,
    oneTimePrepayment: 0,
    rateType: 'variable',
    rateCompounding: 'semi-Annual',
  } as SimpleOutgoingDataType,
  reducers: {
    setSimpleOutgoingData: (
      state,
      { payload }: PayloadAction<SimpleOutgoingDataType>,
    ) => ({
      ...state,
      ...payload,
    }),
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [clearStore.type]: () => {},
  },
})
```

this is saga

```
function* postSimpleMortgageCalc(
  action: ReturnType<typeof actions.postSimpleMortgageCalc>,
) {
  const { payload } = action

  yield put(actions.setIsLoading(true))

  try {
    const {
      data: { result },
    } = yield call(() => API.simpleMortgageCalc.post(payload))

    yield put(
      actions.setSimpleMortgageData({
        principalPayment: 0,
        interestPayment: 0,
        ...result,
      }),
    )
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  } finally {
    yield put(actions.setIsLoading(false))
  }
}

export function* watchSimpleMortgageSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(actions.postSimpleMortgageCalc.type, postSimpleMortgageCalc)
}
```

This is root saga

```
export default function* RootSaga() {
  yield all([fork(watchSimpleMortgageSaga)])
}
```

This is root Reducer

```
export default combineReducers({
  simpleMortgage: simpleMortgageReducer,
})
```

This is store index file

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2, // see "Merge Process" section for details.
}

const pReducer = persistReducer<StateType, any>(persistConfig, RootReducer)

const sagaMiddleware = saga()

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: pReducer,
  middleware: [
    ...getDefaultMiddleware({ thunk: false, serializableCheck: false }),
    sagaMiddleware,
  ],
  devTools: true,
})

sagaMiddleware.run(RootSaga)

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>

export default store

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

And this is app index file

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App domElement={1} />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to react strictmode. Disable it and the request will be only sent once.

Checkout this too:
https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).